# Most compatible approach for defining properties in JavaScript which even runs on Mobile

Tags: javascript, html

There are various ways to create object properties in JavaScript, using defineProperty, getter and setter etc...

**Ref:**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty

http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/

- My query is which is the most compatible way which works in all modern browser and all 
  mobile browser.

**edit**
I am looking for a cross browser solution which allow me to define properties with getter and setter functions. And this is a required functionality which I cant ignore.

**Best Regards**

Answer (score 1):

The methods defined in ECMA-262 ed 3 are by far the most compatible and should be supported by all javascript environments in use (though object literal was not available in very early IE, around version 3), i.e.:

#### Object literal:

```
var obj = {foo: 'foo', bar: 'bar", ...}
```

#### Square bracket notation:

```
var obj = {};
obj['foo'] = 'foo';
obj['bar'] = 'bar';
```

#### Dot notation:

```
var obj = {};
obj.foo = 'foo';
obj.bar = 'bar';
```

Comment: You asked for the most compatible way to define properties, so that's what I answered. If you want to define getters and setters, that's quite a different thing. ES5 features will only work in recent browsers, mobile or other (and the distinction between mobile and other is becoming less clear). Writing your own getters and setters that are compatible with ES3 should work everywhere.

Comment: When you use the word property, it is assumed that getter and setter functions are associated with that... Anyway, have a look at this. http://jsperf.com/object-defineproperty-vs-definegetter-vs-normal This test defines various approaches for creating properties... But there are only few test-runs for mobile browsers.